# simplify cout << "mkdir: cannot create directory '" << arguments[1] << "': File exists\n";

Tags: c++

How do I change this it to 2 lines instead of 1 line?
Was told lines should very rarely be longer than 80 characters

```
cout << "mkdir: cannot create directory '" << arguments[1] << "': File exists\n";
```

Comment: Line-lengths today is purely a stylistic thing, since monitors today have enough resolution to display very long lines. And as all stylistic things, it's very subjective. So you do what you think is best.

Comment: As for actually breaking the line up, remember that C++ is a *free-form* language, you can have any *kind* of whitespace and any *number* of it (even none) between tokens, so just add a newline in the editor wherever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a newline in:

```
 cout << "mkdir: cannot create directory '" << arguments[1] 
      << "': File exists\n";
```

> *"One more question ..."*

Same thing

```
 if (arguments[1][0] < '0' || 
     arguments[1][0] > '7' || 
     strlen(arguments[1]) > 1)
```

Comment: One more question: how do i change this into 2 lines?                                  if (arguments[1][0] < '0' || arguments[1][0] > '7' || strlen(arguments[1]) > 1)

Comment: @Wii: you can put newlines in anywhere you like except in the middle of an identifier (i.e. not in the middle of "arguments", "if" or "strlen"), and not inside the two-character token `||` nor the single character literals '0' and '7'.  Anywhere else is fine, but it's common practice to put a newline after an operator like `||` as that visually communicates that there's more to come on the next line, and to indent the continued lines to help show they're logically grouped.  `<<` is often put at the start of the continuing line - just reads better - bit of an art to this.

Comment: @TonyD: ... and not inside string literals

Comment: @undur_gongor ... unless you use raw string literals, or escape the line break with a `\\`.

Comment: @undur_gongor: I only listed things appearing in the code in the comment above, but yes - in general there're string and numeric literals, and many other multi-character operators (e.g. `==`, `>>=`, `::`, `->`, `^=` etc.), and some special requirements for keeping preprocessor stuff on one line or using trailing `\`s.  Suddenly it sounds more complicated than it feels in day-to-day programming!  Cheers.